# Matlab Too Many Input Arguments and How to set default values on that

Tags: matlab

There are 8 input arguments in my function `unstable_L(T1,T2,z1,z2,z3,z0h,z0m,U)`.

I would like to create this function with 5 required  inouts and 3 optional inputs in which the optional value will be my default values that I have set if the user do not fill in. How can I make it? Is there any mistake in my coding?

```
nargin = 8;
if nargin > 8
    disp (" the function unstable_L_new has only maximum of 8 input paramaters")

else
% Fill in unset optional values.
switch nargin
    case 5
        if isempty(z0h)
        z0h = 0.005;

        elseif isempty(z0m)
        z0m = 0.005;

        elseif isempty(U)
        U = 2.0;

        end

    case 6
        if isempty(z0m)
        z0m = 0.005;

        elseif isempty(U)
        U = 2.0;

        end

    case 7
        if isempty(U)
        U = 2.0;
        end
end
end
```

Comment: It depends on which arguments are optional, are they always the same? Or does the function just require 5/8 to work?

Comment: the last three arguments are optional, but the function must have all 8 inputs to function.
I would like to write the function in which in case the user does not have enough data for the last three arguments, then matlab will recognise the last three arguments and fill in the default values that I set.
is it posiible to do that?

Comment: See my answer below, that should do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your problem is that your last three arguments `z0h`, `z0m` and `U` are optional.

The way you can make this work is by checking if they `exist`

```
function unstable_L(T1,T2,z1,z2,z3,z0h,z0m,U)

    if (~exist('z0h', 'var'))
        z0h = 1;
    end

    if (~exist('z0m', 'var'))
        z0m = 0.005;
    end

    if (~exist('U', 'var'))
        U = 2.0;
    end

    % rest of function
```

Comment: it works~! woa! Thanks a lot for helping! I really appreciate it

Comment: Glad I could help, however, for future use of SO take a brief look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers